# ExecuteNonQuery requires an open available connection. The connection’s current state is closed

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

i want to check if the invoice number in invoices table if not exists then add new invoice number an fill invoice details in invoicedetails table, else if it is exists in invoices table just i want to update the Total field in case if the invoice has more than one item,
in the class:

```
StockClass stk = new StockClass();

stk.Quantity = txtQuantity.Text;
stk.StockID = txtStockID.Text;
stk.QtyUpdate();
MessageBox.Show("Stock record has been Successfully updated ");

InvoiceClass invclass = new InvoiceClass();

try
{
OleDbConnection myConnection = default(OleDbConnection);
myConnection = new OleDbConnection(cs);

OleDbCommand myCommand = default(OleDbCommand);

myCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT InvoiceNo FROM Invoices WHERE InvoiceNo = @InvoiceNo", myConnection);
OleDbParameter invono = new OleDbParameter("@username", OleDbType.VarChar);
invono.Value = txtInvoiceNo.Text;
myCommand.Parameters.Add(invono);


myCommand.Connection.Open();

OleDbDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

if (myReader.Read() == true)
{
invclass.InvoiceNo = txtInvoiceNo.Text;
invclass.Total = txtGrandTotal.Text;
invclass.Date = InvDate.Text;

invclass.updateinvoNumber();
}
else
{
invclass.InvoiceNo = txtInvoiceNo.Text;
invclass.Total = txtGrandTotal.Text;
invclass.Date = InvDate.Text;

invclass.AddNewinvoNumber();

invclass.InvoiceID = txtInvoiceNo.Text;
invclass.ProductID = txtProdID.Text;
invclass.ProName = txtProdName.Text;
invclass.ProType = txtProdType.Text;
invclass.ProSize = txtProdSize.Text;
invclass.Quantity = textQty.Text;
invclass.UnitPrice = txtPrice.Text;
invclass.Total = textTotal.Text;
invclass.Date = InvDate.Text;
invclass.CustName = txtCustName.Text;
invclass.EmpName = txtEmpName.Text;

invclass.AddNew();
}
if (myConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
{
myConnection.Dispose();
}
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}


OleDbDataAdapter ad = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select ProName, ProType, ProSize, Quantity, UnitPrice, Total, CustName, EmpName, date From InvoiceDetails WHERE [InvoiceID] = ?", cs);

ad.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@InvoiceID", OleDbType.VarChar);
ad.SelectCommand.Parameters["@InvoiceID"].Value = txtInvoiceNo.Text;

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ad.Fill(ds, "Invo");
DGV1.DataSource = ds.Tables["Invo"];
DGV1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
}
```

When it is not exist it is working good, but when its exist i am facing an error

> ExecuteNonQuery requires an open available connection. The connection’s current state is closed

```
public void updateinvoNumber()
{
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|StoreSys.mdb"))
using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE [invoices] SET [InvoiceNo]=?, [Total] = ?,[Date] = ? WHERE [InvoiceNo] = ?", conn))
{
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("p0", InvoiceNo);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("p1", Total);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("p2", Date);



cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
}
}
```

Comment: All your `= default(...)` things are useless noise.

Comment: can u please provide the code for updateinvoNumber()? There could be something wrong in that code.

Comment: Where is the `ExecuteNonQuery`?

Comment: using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|StoreSys.mdb"))
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE [invoices] SET [InvoiceNo]=?, [Total] = ?,[Date] = ? WHERE [InvoiceNo] = ?", conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("p0", InvoiceNo);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("p1", Total);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("p2", Date);



                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
            }

Comment: Please add the code you just added to your post by editing it.  It's unreadable inside a comment.  **EDIT:** I can still read enough to tell that you never call `conn.Open()` before using and executing the `OldDbCommand`.  So, of course, you will get the error.

Answer (score 5):

I guess I should post this as an answer...

You are not opening your connection, plain and simple.

Instead of...

```
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|StoreSys.mdb"))
using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE [invoices] SET [InvoiceNo]=?, [Total] = ?,[Date] = ? WHERE [InvoiceNo] = ?", conn))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("p0", InvoiceNo);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("p1", Total);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("p2", Date);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
```

You need... (notice the `conn.Open();`)

```
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|StoreSys.mdb"))
{
    conn.Open(); // <-- You forgot this.
    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE [invoices] SET [InvoiceNo]=?, [Total] = ?,[Date] = ? WHERE [InvoiceNo] = ?", conn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("p0", InvoiceNo);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("p1", Total);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("p2", Date);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        // conn.Close(); <-- you don't need this btw. This will happen automatically as you exit the "using" block.
    }
}
```

Comment: He's right, even though you opened a connection prior to calling the updateinvoiceno() method, you created a new instance of conn inside the updateinvoiceno() method.  Since this is new, it isn't open unless you open it. with `conn.Open();`

Answer (score 4):

Okay, I see the problem. The problem is perfectly described in the error message: you don't have a connection open.

You do it up top with the myCommand object: `myCommand.Connection.Open();`

However with the OleDbDataAdapter object named 'ad', even thought you specify a connection string, you have to explicitly open the connection.

I just visited Microsofts page for the OleDbDataAdapter constructor overload you are using (the one with two strings) located at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2f8y4737.aspx and it had this to say, under the remarks section.

> This overload of the OleDbDataAdapter constructor uses the selectConnectionString parameter to set the SelectCommand property. **However, it does not open the connection. You still must explicitly open the connection.**

Looking at your code, I believe the smallest change you can do to accomplish this would be to add the code:

```
ad.SelectCommand.Connection.Open();
```

in between setting the SqlParameters and filling the DataSet:

```
ad.SelectCommand.Parameters["@InvoiceID"].Value = txtInvoiceNo.Text;

**ad.SelectCommand.Connection.Open();** // <- HERE

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ad.Fill(ds, "Invo");
```

However, I'm not 100% sure that that will work as shown, as I've never opened a connection in this way, I usually explicitly create an a connection object, and open it before even setting the command. Also, you are going to want to use 'using' statements to ensure the database connection gets closed and disposed, otherwise you will leave a connection open with the SQL server, and there are only limited number of those.  I have seen applications that borf the server by creating and failing to close too many connections in a short time.

So if the code `ad.SelectCommand.Connection.Open();` does not work, try creating the connection object explicitly like you do above, and then you can set associate the connection object with the OleDbDataAdapter in its constructor in place of the connection string:

```
using(OleDbConnection myConnection2 = new OleDbConnection(cs))
{
    myConnection2.Open();

    using(OleDbDataAdapter ad = new OleDbDataAdapter(/*truncated*/, myConnection2))
    {
        [...]
```